# can't find published bot via Skype search

Tags: botframework

Question is not about programming, but stackoverflow.com is only community support resource mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/bot-framework/resources-links-help

I need to show a Skype bot to my boss, the way clients would see it. I created a new bot, published it, linked to out CRM, but can't find it via Skype bot search. It is listed in Bot Directory, i tried to disable and and re-enable publishing.

If I add it to Skype contacts via direct link from bot's profile page, it works just fine, sends and receives messages etc. I've waited for weeks in hope that bot search index just has been slow but no dice, bot still works but can't be found in Skype client. Other bots from directory can be found instantly. I tried at 5 different PCs. Status for Skype Publishing is Approved.

What can I do to get my bot to Skype search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype bots are only searchable in the bot directory if they are "Featured" or otherwise highlighted by the Skype business team.

As you can see on the help page [What Skype bots are available?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34655/what-skype-bots-are-available#joinlinkbots) - not all bots can be directly added via the directory. In the section [What bots can be added directly that are not available in the Skype directory?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34655/what-skype-bots-are-available#joinlinkbots) you can see examples of non-directory bots which can only be added via web link.

For Bot Framework bots, the same scenario applies.  Your bot will only be searchable in the Skype bot directory if it is published and is a "Featured" bot.  Otherwise, the official way to add the bot is to share the "join" URL generated on the "Channels" page of the [Bot Portal](https://botframework.com).

To view your bot's Skype "join" URL, go to the Channels page in the Bot Portal, right click on the "Skype" text and select "Copy Link Address".

Example Skype bot add-to-contacts "join" URL:

```
https://join.skype.com/bot/257389ac-afdb-473a-9b98-1234567890
```